# regextract in google sheets to find twitter usernames

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of tweets and want to isolate username mentions in Google Sheets. Somehow, regexps that work in R or other languages are not doing the job there.

An example:

```
RT @Neromoto: @cazainfractor inconsciente agresiva y poco ciudadana conductora
```

Desired output:

```
@Neromoto
@cazainfractor
```

I have tried this: `REGEXEXTRACT(B1,(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b)`.

Comment: In R, you define a regex in a C string literal where you have to double backslashes. In Google Sheets, you should use single backslashes. What is the regex that works in R and does not work in the Google Sheets? (Note that R is a specific case since there are 3 (or 4 if we take into account Tcl used by gsubfn) different regex flavors there depending on what package/options you are  using).

Comment: I have tried this REGEXEXTRACT(B1,(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b)

Comment: I think you can use `=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"\B@\w{1,15}")`. If you really have strings with `@@` and you need to use that regex of yours, make the first group non-capturing - `=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"(?:^|[^@\w])(@\w{1,15})")`. That will get you the first match, BTW. Maybe you want to actually use `REGEXREPLACE`?

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the quotations....but your code works better :)

Comment: Well, also try `=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"(\B@\w{1,15})\s*|.","$1 ")`. Could you please let me know what works for you so that I could post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})\b` regex pattern must be put inside a string literal, i.e. double quotes. Then note that every capturing group will be output, you may want to make the first group *non-capturing* by replacing `(` with `(?:`. Also, the last `\b` is redundant, after the last `\w` matched, there will be either the end of string, or the non-word char.

I'd rather suggest

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"\B@\w{1,15}")
```

[image]

Or

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"(\B@\w{1,15})\s*|.","$1 ")
```

[image]

**Details**:

- `\B`  - a non-word boundary (that is, before `@`, there can be either start of string or a non-word char)
- `@`  - a `@` char
- `\w{1,15}` - 1 to 15 word chars (if you do not care about the length, replace `{1,15}` with `+`)

And the second regex details:

- `(\B@\w{1,15})\s*` - Group 1 capturing `@` at the non-word boundary position,  1 to 15 word chars and then 0+ whitespaces (in the replacement, the `$1` backreference inserts the found mentions back into the resulting string)
- `|` - or
- `.` - any 1 char.